# Create a MySQL trigger that affects only current row

Tags: mysql, triggers, row

I want to set a trigger that effects only the row that is inserted, not the other rows.

So I need something different than for each row. Here is what I have now.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON student
FOR EACH ROW SET @starost =new.starost+2;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You nearly had it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON student 
FOR EACH ROW SET new.starost =new.starost+2;
```

It will add two to the `starost` field before insertion

Comment: This corrected the user's problem but doesn't address the title's question. Mootinator's answer does that.

Answer (score 10):

`FOR EACH ROW` in an `INSERT` trigger only affects the inserted rows.  The case where it would handle more than one row (and as such the name implies it handles more than one row) would be on a bulk insert like when using the `INSERT. . .SELECT` syntax.

Comment: This is the Real Answer. Although @ed-heal 's answer corrected the mistake. But this should be the real conceptual and theoretical answer.